# VM Windows Standard 2019 license cost

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have ONE VM instance (16 simulated cores) in a cloud provider with Windows Server 2019 Standard on it.

I do NOT want to install VMs inside it. I only want to use OS itself.

Cloud provider is charging me ~3,300 EUR/year for this license (only OS, no remote access CAL's).

This seems like really really expensive just for one OS license. 
They say I can not buy and use my own license (~1000EUR one time cost) because it is virtual machine and I will need Datacenter edition. Are they giving me correct info?
At the same time other clouds offer Standard edition for ~550EUR/year on *dedicated* servers.

Comment: Server Fault cannot answer licensing questions. See  [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: If other providers offer a less expensive option, switch to them.

Comment: It is impossible for us to tell whether the provider legitimately needs Datacenter features and you unfortunately are not sharing the cost with many other guest OSEs, Standard is acceptable but they don't know how to reduce their costs, or they have kept costs low but enjoy large profit margins. And that's before complications like CALs.

Comment: It just my common sense tells me that 3k/year is bloody expensive to just run one Windows. I believe im being ripped off, and asked community for help. Got this closed. :((
BTW I did talk to 3 different MS gold partners, all gives different information. And that is because "MS licensing is so complicated". Look Im just a guy who needs one instance of windows running in a cloud.